# Is that possible to define mongo::DBClientReplicaSet as a global variable in a class?

Tags: c++, mongodb, extern, legacy, mongodb-replica-set

I am using c++ legacy driver, I built a class with many mongoDB operations in different functions.

I don't want to define the `mongo::DBClientReplicaSet` in every function but if I define it in the global level, I had another problem because I need to call `mongo::client::initialize` before I construct any driver objects, or BSON for that matter. That means if I call `mongo::client::initialize` in the class construct function, I cannot define `mongo::DBClientReplicaSet` before that. So it cannot be declared in the global level. I tried "`extern mongo::DBClientReplicaSet xxxx`" and then defined it in class construct function but got link error :

> error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class
>   mongo::DBClientReplicaSet xxxx"

because we cannot use `mongo::DBClientReplicaSet` without parameters.

Does anybody know a solution for this?

Comment: Why are you using the legacy driver, rather than the newer C++11 driver, mongocxx?